# VB.net load dll

Tags: vb.net, dll, load, .net-assembly, reflector

I have been attempting to load a DLL using Reflector

```
Imports System.Reflection
```

I have a simple DLL file written in c++ using /CLR (this is the entire file)

```
using namespace System;


namespace ASSEMBLE{

public class REM{
    public:
        int VALUE(){
            return 100;
        }

    };

};
```

And inside my VB.net butten click event i have

```
 Dim dllPath As String = "C:\Users\richard\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\link\link\bin\Release\dlltest.dll"
        ' load the assembly 
        Dim assembly1 As System.Reflection.Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath)
        ' get the type 
        Dim t As Type = assembly1.GetType("ASSEMBLE.REM")
        ' create an instance and add it. 
        Dim c As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)


        MsgBox(t.InvokeMember("VAULE", BindingFlags.Default Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, c, {}))
```

When event triggered (ie. i load the dll) i get the error:

```
Method 'ASSEMBLE.REM.VALUE' not found
```

Using:

```
<DllImport("DLL.dll")> Public Shared Function VALUE() As Integer
        End Function
```

is not an option. I need to load the DLL after runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your `REM` class is an unmanaged class, and therefore reflection cannot see its methods. Using the /CLR compile option does not automatically force all classes to be managed. It just allows you to have managed classes in your project.

To allow the call to `InvokeMember`, you need to make `REM` a managed class. This can be done by adding `ref` to the class declaration like so:

```c
public ref class REM{
    ...
};
```